# ElGamal in a different group

Tags: encryption, elgamal-encryption

Can Elgamal be secure in $\bmod {n^2}$? Meaning instead of using a prime order group to use a group where DCR assumption holds?

Comment: With "DCR",  do you mean "Decisional composite residuosity assumption" form Paillier?. Then I would suggest it has nothing to do with ElGamal, because it relates a modulus $n^2$ to the _same_ exponent $n$.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of multiplicative subgroups in the ring of divisor classes modulo $n^2$. One particular subgroup (with easy logarithm) is generated by $(n+1)$. You would not want to use it for ElGamal. Other subgroup (of large enough order) are fine.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if anyone has looked at this question specifically. However, Diffie-Hellman modulo a composite $n=pq$ is actually as hard as factoring. See this [paper](https://omereingold.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/cgdh.pdf) by Biham, Boneh, and Reingold. It is worth seeing if a similar reduction can be proven for DCR.

Comment: Yehuda the link you provided does not work. Can you tell me the title? Thanks

Comment: I fixed the link. The title is: Breaking Generalized Diffie-Hellman Modulo a Composite is no Easier than Factoring. Regarding DCR and factoring, factoring is at least as hard as DCR (if factoring is easy then DCR certainly is; the opposite direction is not known). My suggestion is to try to prove that DDH is hard mod $n^2$ if DCR is hard. I don't know if it's true, but it's an interesting question.

Comment: So the general framework towards this would be to construct a PPT A to break DCR by using a PPT B who breaks DDH

Comment: Also with respect to DCR and factoring i was meaning what you wrote. My semantics were wrong  though. Wrong vocabulary to describe a common technical agreement. You need to know the right words to communicate your ideas, but not when you work alone on them :)

Comment: From "Extended-DDH and Lossy Trapdoor Functions": "This series of works generalizing DDH-based constructions suggests the heuristic
that “anything that can be done with DDH can be done with DCR or QR.”
Like any heuristic it is not completely accurate, but it appears to provide the
right intuition"

Comment: Also something similar is proven in lemma 1 here http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/256.pdf